# Does an English version of Burdick's book on Hubert Lanz exist?

Tags: translation, charles-b-burdick

Wasn't sure whether to ask on history SE or here, but am trying this.

In the German language book *Hubert Lanz: General der Gebirgstruppe* by the American professor [Charles B. Burdick](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_B._Burdick), who does not seem to have any English language wiki page, it says it was translated from "American", but no English language book by him on Lanz seems to exist.

Does anybody know how this happened? Did Burdick write a manuscript in English that was never published, but then translated into German?

Have tried contacting the [Burdick Archive](http://www.sjsu.edu/burdick/) but with no results.